# How do I stop a fixed, 100% width element from overlapping the browser's scroll-bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website has 4 columns-each for one of the pages. Thus, the width of the mask in the wrapper is 400%. Navigation is made with the scrollTo jquery plugin, both vertically and horizontally.

Because the navigation bar was set to `position: fixed;` and `width: 100%;`, it was overlapping the div's scroll. I gave it `right: 17px;` but it also makes the pages scroll +17 extra pixels.

Is there any way of setting the width of each of the pages to 100% - 17 pixels?

Otherwise, how to avoid putting `right: 17px;` on navigation without having to overlap the scroll?

Link to the website: [www.inbrackets.dk/test](http://www.inbrackets.dk/test)

Comment: where is the 4 columns? do you mean the horizontal navigation?

Comment: Yes, that's the horizontal navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not mess with the right positioning at all. Your scroll bar is on your `#wrapper` div, and since it is `position: absolute`, I would adjust some settings on that to get the scroll bar to *sit below* the `#nav`.

First, remove the `height` from the `#wrapper` and then change/add the following css to `#wrapper`:

```
top: 70px ; /* clears your nav */
bottom: 0px; /* gives it the height; puts the scroll bar at the bottom of the screen */
```

Comment: Good catch, i was glancing at the site and didn't recognize on which element the scrollbar was. This of course is a nice and clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc).

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 17px);
width:         calc(100% - 17px);
```

However this has limited support - it is not supported in IE8 and lower.

sidenote: in several browsers, especially on windows machines the scrollbar is 20px wide, so you need `right:20px`. Also your font is extremely hard to read on my machine:

[image]

Comment: Will I be right if I tell if `calc()` has been added in `css3`? That's one of  the best `css` features so far :) +1

Comment: Yes, you are. Indeed it's a nice feature unfortunately IE once again is the showstopper here with IE8 not supporting it. ANother nice feature similar to this is [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) which support is really good.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using calc, and set your fixed nav to just span left: 0, and right: 0;

```
position: fixed;
top:0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8LXV/